# Can't access ItemInvoked event handler of WindowsXamlHost control

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, uwp-xaml

I use xamlIslands to host a custom UWP control in a WPF, .NetCore3 project. I followed instructions from this MSDN article in order to use UWP controls in WPF - [Host a custom UWP control in a WPF app using XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands)

Other articles mention that the `WindowsXamlHost`'s `ChildChanged` event handler is used to access the underlying UWP control's properties, handle events etc. Therefore, I am trying to access the ItemInvoked handler within the WPF project's `window.xaml.cs` file

I tried the linked article above's code. ItemInvoked it not listed by the dropdown as a choosable event for `userControl` below:

```
        private void WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowsXamlHost windowsXamlHost = sender as WindowsXamlHost;
            global::MyUWPApp.CustomControls.myNavigationView userControl =
                windowsXamlHost.GetUwpInternalObject() as global::MyUWPApp.CustomControls.myNavigationView;
        }
```

Another Approach which does give ItemInvoked as optional event handler:

```
    private void WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var host = (WindowsXamlHost)sender;
        var myNavView = host.Child as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView;

        myNavView.ItemInvoked += MyNavView_ItemInvoked; ;
    }
    private void MyNavView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Building that breaks on `myNavView.ItemInvoked += MyNavView_ItemInvoked;` with error `System.ArgumentException: 'Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.`  
Hovering with mouse on `myNavView`  within the code above gives info: `(local variable) NavigationView myNavView`
I guess that does not work because it is not an instance of the object.

General info:
The custom control is "hosted" in a UWP project, which is linked to the WPF project. As according to the article mentioned above. Within the WPF project window where I want to use the custom control, the following event handlers are accessible which seem relevant or possibly useful, in `window.xaml`:

```
        <xaml:WindowsXamlHost InitialTypeName="MyUWPApp.CustomControls.myNavigationView"
                              ChildChanged="WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged"
                              Loaded="WindowsXamlHost_Loaded_1"
                              Initialized="WindowsXamlHost_Initialized"
                              />
```

I want to be able to access `ItemInvoked` event handler to properly manage selections in a UWP `NavigationView`, as according to this MSDN article: [Using the NavigationView in your UWP applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/05/06/using-the-navigationview-in-your-uwp-applications/)